# Proving that $S^{1} * S^{1}$ (join) is homotopiclly equivalent to $S^{3}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Proving that $S^{1} * S^{1}$ is homotopiclly equivalent to $S^{3}$.

I know that the definition of homotopy equivalence from Allen Hatcher is:
A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is called a homotopy equivalence if there is a map $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g$ homotopic to $\mathbb{1_{Y}}$ and $g \circ f$ homotopic to  $\mathbb{1_{X}}$.

And I have solved $a$ and $c$ in the following question:

> [image]

But I still do not know how to solve this problem, will the solution be similar to one of the above problems?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Also I have this corollary (I am not so much sure that it will be helpful here):

> [image]

If it is helpful here please tell me how?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection between the question about joins and part b) of Hatcher's question 3....

Comment: I said that there may be a connection between part (a) and (c) in question 3, I did not mention (b) at all @JasonDeVito

Comment: Ah, I interpreted "this" in the sentence "But I still do not know how to solve this problem..." as referring to part b.  I am not sure that a) or c) will be used to solve your main question.  The proof I'm thinking of directly shows the two spaces are homemorphic...

Comment: yes but I think this proof of homeomorphism is much more difficult than what I want to prove and also I think there is already 1 on this site proving it. @JasonDeVito

Comment: Try the idea listed in the properties section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)

Comment: $A*B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma(A\wedge B)$ if both are CW. And for $A=B=S^1$ the right side is homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Comment: And how can I prove that $A* B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\sum(A \wedge B)$. Also, how can I prove that   $\sum(A \wedge B)$ is homeomorphic to $S^{3}?$ @freakish

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you refer to Hatcher. In the section "Join" on p.9 Hatcher defines the join $X * Y$ and also the iterated join $X_1 * \ldots *  X_n$. He proves that if each $X_i = S^0$, then the join $X_1 * \ldots *  X_n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. In particular $S^0 * S^0 \approx S^1$ which implies
$$S^1 * S^1 \approx S^0 * S^0 * S^0 * S^0 \approx S^3. $$

Comment: So we do not need to define a homotopy or anything? what about proving that $X*Y $ is homotopically equivalent to $\sum X \wedge Y$?

Comment: In the present case we have a *homeomorphism* which is better than a homotopy equivalence. We do not need to refer to $X *Y \simeq \Sigma(X \wedge Y)$. That is a completely different question.

Comment: So you are saying that the homeomorphism in the book implies the homotopy equivalence required in the main question , is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, homeomorphism always implies homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that to prove two spaces $X,Y$ are homotopy equivalent you must produce a homotopy equivalence $f : X \to Y$, i.e. you must write down a formula for an appropriate function $f : X \to Y$ and then prove that the function you wrote down is a homotopy equivalence. This will require you to write down three more formulas: one for an appropriate function $g : X \to Y$ to be a homotopy inverse of $f$; one for a homotopy $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$ between $g \circ f$ and the identity; and one for a homotopy $H' : Y \to [0,1] \to Y$ between $f \circ g$ and the identity.

In this case, as noted in a comment, you have the option of proving the stronger statement that $S^1 * S^1$ and $S^3$ are homeomorphic. This still requires you to produce a homeomorphism $f : S^1 * S^1 \to S^3$, this time by writing down a formula for an appropriate function $f$ and then proving that the function you wrote down is a homeomorphism.

If you're lucky, someone else will have written the formula down for you, and that appears to be the case here: you can just read p. 9 of Hatcher to find the formula, according to the answer of @PaulFrost.

But if you're not so lucky, then your job might be hard. You have to use your mathematical experience/imagination/expertise, or whatever else you might have at your disposal, to figure out the correct formula.

Comment: What about proving that $S^m * S^n$ is homotopically equivalent to S^{m + n +1}? is it by induction after taking the above statement as a basis?

Comment: I would say that for this problem, the proof is not by induction, instead by generalization. You still have to write down the correct formula for the homeomorphism $S^m * S^n \mapsto S^{m+n+1}$. It does look a lot like the one for $S^1 * S^1 \mapsto S^3$, but you have to figure out how to generalize the formula to work with arbitrary values of the dimensions $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I have tried induction but I realized at the end that I did not use the induction hypothesis so I understood that induction ..... I want to prove that they are hopotopically equivalent not homeomorphic as the proof of homeomorphic is difficult

Comment: Honestly, the proof of homeomorphism is easier if it's possible: you just have to write down one formula for the homeomorphism, and then verify it is bijective, and continuous and its inverse is continuous. For homotopy equivalence, you have several more functions to write down and several properties of each of them to verify.