# Prove that $S^m * S^n$ is homotopically equivalent to $S^{m+n+1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

I feel like the proof is very similar to the one in this link:

[$S^n \backslash  S^m $ homotopy equivalent to $ S^{n-m-1} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/sn-backslash-sm-homotopy-equivalent-to-sn-m-1)

But I could not spot out where will be the difference? could anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is the join @freakish yes I know this property but then how can I use it?  , Also can not I proceed by induction on n as I have already proved the statement for n=m=1?

Comment: Do you know also how can I prove the property you mentioned? @freakish  and is S^n a CW complex??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some facts that you can assemble:

1. For any CW complexes $A,B$ the join $A*B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma(A\wedge B)$
2. For any $n,m$ we have a homeomorphism $S^n\wedge S^m\simeq S^{n+m}$
3. For any $n$ we have a homeomorphism $\Sigma S^n\simeq S^{n+1}$
4. If $A\simeq B$ then $\Sigma A\simeq \Sigma B$
5. Spheres are CW complexes (the simpliest there are)

Can you combine them together to get the result?

Comment: So we can not proceed by induction on n .... correct? as I have proved it for the case $m=n=1$

Comment: I'm not saying this. Maybe we can but I wouldn't know how. This just looked like a simpliest way too me.

Comment: from where in Hatcher you get property 4?

Comment: I'm not sure if property 4 is in Hatcher. But you can prove it yourself. First of all $\Sigma$ also acts on maps, turning $f:X\to Y$ into $\Sigma f:\Sigma X\to \Sigma Y$ via $\Sigma f([x,t])=[f(x), t]$. And this is functorial, meaning $\Sigma (f\circ g)=\Sigma f\circ \Sigma g$. And so (as with any functor) it maps isomorphisms to isomorphisms. In this case "isomorphism" is a "pointed homeomorphism".

Answer (score 1):

In fact $S^m *S^n$ and $S^{m+n+1}$ are homeomorphic. This is proved as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354659:

$S^m \approx S^0 * \ldots * S^0$ witk $m+1$ factors, $S^n \approx S^0 * \ldots * S^0$ witk $n+1$ factors, thus $S^m * S^n \approx S^0 * \ldots * S^0$ witk $m+n+2$ factors, the latter being homeomorphic to $S^{m+n+1}$.

Comment: I want to prove that they are homotopy equivalent only as I do not understand the proof of homeomorphism ..... so I am behaving as if I do not know this homeomorphism

Comment: Can I proceed by induction on n as I have already proved the problem for $m=n=1$?

Comment: The proof of $S^m \approx S^0 * \ldots * S^0$ is "hidden" inductive. I do not know any better proof than that in my answer.